# how to remove Case insensitivitness while searching a text on page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  working on search in a text .Actually I am searching a text from Text .But I am facing a problem in case sensitive .If you search for "n" it work fine .But when you search for "N", it convert the all "n" to  capital "N"and then search .I don't know why it is occurring in searching..?.

here is my try..

http://jsfiddle.net/wjLmx/23/

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "#realTimeContents"; //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted'); //Remove old search highlights  

            //Remove the previous matches
            $span = $('#realTimeContents span');
            $span.replaceWith($span.html());

    if (searchTerm === "&") {
        searchTerm = "&amp;";
        searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
    }
            $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');

            var i = 0;

            $('.next_h').off('click').on('click', function () {
                i++;

                if (i >= $('.match').length) i = 0;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });
            $('.previous_h').off('click').on('click', function () {

                i--;

                if (i < 0) i = $('.match').length - 1;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });




            if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.searchButtonClickText_h', function (event) {

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
    if (!searchAndHighlight($('.textSearchvalue_h').val())) {
        alert("No results found");
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following line:

```
$(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
```

which replace the matches with the searchTerm (e.g. "N").

Try replacing it to something like the following to replace it with what was matched:

```
$(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + matches[0] + "</span>"));
```

If you want to stop the search being case insensitive, drop the `i` from your regex.

```
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "g");
```

Comment: But when i search "N" in my fiddle it search for "n".If i don't want to search for "n".Tell you again actually when i search for "N" .it search for "n".I don't do like that

Comment: :( :( Both solution is not working in IOS ..Still facing first problem in IOS Ipad

Comment: is there any other solution like search for node text,..?